# Regex: How to recover roman numbered titles and their respective contents

Tags: regex, pcre2

After extract text from PDFs files using pdftotext, I am trying to recover some their titles and respective contents.

This batch of files have a pattern of a new line followed by a roman number followed (or not) by dot or hyphen and the title followed by break line.

So I tried this pattern:

```
^[^\S\n]*([CLXVI]{1,7})\.\s?(.*?)\n([\S\s]*)(?=[CLXVI]{1,7})
```

But did not worked as expected:

https://regex101.com/r/vX4aB4/1

The expected result was something like:

```
group title -> Breve Síntese da Demanda
group content -> Lorem ipsum dolor ... faucibus.
group title -> Bla Bla bla
group content -> Lorem ipsum dolor ... faucibus.
group title -> Do Mérito
group content -> Lorem ipsum dolor ... commodo.
group title -> Conclusão
group content -> Lorem ipsum dolor ... .
```

So how Can I improve that to recover properly each title and their respective contents?

Comment: Can you clarify what is the expected result of a regex? Should the regex match a title + its content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a negative [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to prevent skipping over, e.g.

```
^(\h*+[CLXVI]{1,7}\.)\h*(.+)\s*((?:(?!(?1)).*\R?)*)
```

[See your updated demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/j5X0Bt/4) - Use in `(?m)` [multiline mode](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-modifiers.html#multiline)

---

The relevant part `(?!(?1))` prevents skipping over *first group* pattern.
This is a PCRE regex, it uses [group reference](https://www.regular-expressions.info/subroutine.html) and [possessive quantifier](https://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html).

Comment: Np sir, take some rest we all need it  cheers